# Zone.js has detected that ZoneAwarePromise `(window|global).Promise` has been overwritten in Angular 8

Tags: typescript, angular8

Hiii All, Previously i used **Angular 6** and after I Migrating into **Angular 8** which is Done but After Sometime it gives me error

```
main.js:11770 Error: Zone.js has detected that ZoneAwarePromise `(window|global).Promise` has been overwritten.
Most likely cause is that a Promise polyfill has been loaded after Zone.js (Polyfilling Promise api is not necessary when zone.js is loaded. If you must load one, do so before loading zone.js.)
    at Function.assertZonePatched (polyfills.js:2901)
    at new NgZone (vendor.js:80474)
    at getNgZone (vendor.js:81501)
    at PlatformRef.bootstrapModuleFactory (vendor.js:81344)
    at vendor.js:81419
    at scripts.js:22096
```

**package.json**

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^8.0.3",
    "@angular/cdk": "^8.2.3",
    "@angular/common": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~8.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~8.0.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.1.4",
    "@ng-idle/core": "^8.0.0-beta.4",
    "@ng-idle/keepalive": "^8.0.0-beta.4",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^3.6.0",
    "@types/highcharts": "^7.0.0",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.31",
    "ag-grid-community": "^21.2.2",
    "angular-calendar": "^0.27.20",
    "angular2-draggable": "^2.3.2",
    "angular2-highcharts": "^0.5.5",
    "angular2-moment": "^1.9.0",
    "chart.js": "^2.9.2",
    "crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
    "date-fns": "^1.30.1",
    "exceljs": "^3.3.1",
    "export-to-csv": "^0.2.1",
    "file-saver": "^2.0.2",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "jspdf": "^1.5.3",
    "jspdf-autotable": "^3.2.10",
    "moment": "^2.24.0",
    "ng-circle-progress": "^1.5.1",
    "ng2-charts": "^2.3.0",
    "ng2-order-pipe": "^0.1.5",
    "ng2-pdf-viewer": "^6.0.2",
    "ng2-search-filter": "^0.5.1",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^5.2.0",
    "ngx-daterangepicker-material": "^2.1.8",
    "ngx-pagination": "^4.1.0",
    "ngx-toastr": "^11.2.1",
    "ngx-tooltip": "0.0.9",
    "ngx-ui-switch": "^8.2.0",
    "number-to-words": "^1.2.4",
    "primeicons": "^2.0.0",
    "primeng": "^8.1.1",
    "quill": "^1.3.6",
    "rxjs": "~6.4.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.3",
    "ts-xlsx": "0.0.11",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.9.1"
  },
```

and I install all Dependency Related to my Project after i got error suddenly don't know which dependency issue or any other problem occured after i research into many resource from the internet all the solution i implemented into my project but not going **ZoneAwarePromise** Error

I found this solution i.e `{ ngZone: 'noop'}` which is **main.ts** file

**main.ts**

```
platformBrowserDynamic()
  .bootstrapModule(MainModule, { ngZone: 'noop'})
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

after I applied this `{ ngZone: 'noop'}` into **main.ts file** error is not showing but My Project API is not Calling.

So Please Help me out where is the problem occured and I am using **Angular 8** with **Typescript** Version **~3.4.3**

Comment: try deleting `node_modules` and make `npm install`. Try the same after `npm update`

Comment: done same error

Comment: zone.js seems like the problem for you. Maybe it has issues with nodejs/npm versions that you use

Comment: don't know what is the issue

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and i found a solution here: https://medium.com/angular-in-depth/do-you-still-think-that-ngzone-zone-js-is-required-for-change-detection-in-angular-16f7a575afef

1. Import in your component:

   ```
   import { ApplicationRef } from '@angular/core';
   ```
2. Inject:

   ```
   constructor(
    private _appService: ApplicationRef,
   ) { }
   ```
3. Every time you need a change detection do this:

   ```
   this._appService.tick();
   ```

This work for me.

P. D. Sorry for my poor english.